# What is wrong with my mysql join query?

Tags: mysql

I am fetching records from database and wanted to show results from two tables one is named 'ads_data' and 2nd one is 'ads_images' in ads_data I am saving related data to ad like phone, name, email etc & in ads_images I am saving images for that ads the problem I am facing is when I try to fetch record using mysql Joins like INNER it repeats my results means with every ad image it is showing same related data of images. I just want to display data once then it's all related images.

below is my query:

```
SELECT * ,  `ads_data`.`id` AS  `ads_id` 
FROM  `ads_data` 
INNER JOIN  `ad_images` ON  `ad_images`.`ad_id` =  `ads_data`.`id` 
WHERE  `ads_data`.`category_group` =  '3'
ORDER BY  `ads_data`.`id` ASC
```

I have tried group by order, unique etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_concat(ad_images.image) AS images` in your select statement.

More details here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/